# Lazarus: Install Anchor Docking

Tags: raspberry-pi, lazarus, freepascal

I'm trying to install Anchor Docking for Lazarus on my Pi

Lazarus v0.9.30.4-6 || Linux raspberrypi 3.12.28 armv6l

At first I used package manager. In the install list, AnchorDocking 0.6 and AnchorDockingDsgn 0.5 always show they will install next time rebuild IDE, but nothing installed although I did rebuild.

So I managed to install manually: packages -> open package files ->
 /usr/lib/lazarus/default/examples/anchordocking/anchordocking.lpk
Compile and install, all fine. Now AnchorDocking 6.0 is installed (in the package list)

Next step:
/usr/lib/lazarus/default/examples/anchordocking/design/anchordockingdsgn.lpk

Fatal: can't find unit anchordockingpkg used by lazarus
But when I add anchordockpkg to files list, it's already there, still can't find unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't add the right unit to your use clause. You must add `AnchorDocking`, eg:

```
uses 
  classes, sysutils, AnchorDocking;
```

Then in the project inspector, click **Add**, tab **New condition** and in Package name field type **AnchorDocking**:

[image: AddRecquirement]

And validate.

Also don't forget to check the example in

`\($LazarusSetupDir)\components\anchordocking\minide`

which is a working example.